# Solving a third order ODE (hypergeometric differential equation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function

Consider the following ODE:

$(x^2 + ax + b)y''' + (cx^2 + dx+e)y'' + (fx+g)y'+hy=0$

where $y$ is a function of $x$ and $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h$ are constants. A special case of this general ODE,

$x^2 y''' - [x^2 - (b_1 + b_2 + 1)x]y'' -[(a_1 + a_2 + 1)x - b_1 b_2]y' - a_1 a_2y=0$

where $a_1,a_2, b_1,b_2$ are constants has a solution given in terms of $_2F_2$ generalized hypergeometric functions. A particular solution being

$_2F_2[a_1,a_2;b_1,b_2;x]$.

What is the solution of the general ODE above (the first equation above)? If it does not have a solution for all parameter values, what conditions are required for it to be solvable?